# Kohana project doesn't work after moving to different server

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3.3

Recently I had to work with Kohana 3.3.1 Framework project (which works). I moved it to my computers localhost, and it doesn't work there. I have set up the mysqli server, tried it on apache and nginx and both give me the same error

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to undefined function __()
SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Kohana/Exception.php [ 53 ]
53      $message = __($message, $variables);
    {
    Fatal error: Call to undefined function __() in /usr/share/nginx/www/system/views/kohana/error.php on line 64
```

Have I forgotten something? I have also tried giving it 777 permission, and still the same error.

Comment: That error message is masking the *real* error message. You need to [turn off Kohana's error handling](https://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/errors#disabling-errorexception-handling) to see the real error.

Answer (score 0):

Please check filenames. Probably during send to server it's change to lowercase. Unix like servers knows difference.

Or check is all files are present on server.
This error is caused beacuse you don't have `system/classes/Kohana/I18n.php` file.

Or check besedir jail.